Next.js cookie problem in getServerSideProps
I have this function in my next.js app :
const getTokenFromCookie = (req) => {
  const parseCookies = (cookieString) => {
    if (!cookieString) {
      return {};
    }
    return Object.fromEntries(
      cookieString.split("; ").map((cookie) => {
        const [name, ...rest] = cookie.split("=");
        return [name, rest.join("=")];
      })
    );
  };
  const cookies = parseCookies(req.headers.cookie);

  const token = cookies._token || null;
  return token;
};

I'm using it inside getServersideProps like this :
export async function getServerSideProps({ req, locale }) {
  const core = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT;

  const token = getTokenFromCookie(req);
  const headers = token ? { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } : {};
/////////////////////////////

On my localhost everithing is working normal but on remote server the token is  null,
How to fix this issue ?
I expect to get token from the cookies
